# why my nexus 6 dosn't open as a folder on my laptop

Tags: file-system, file-transfer, file-management

three month ago I have bought a phone Nexus 6. Firstly when I connected it to my laptop all its folders appeared on a window on my laptop.
Some time later on I tried to move some files out of the phone to laptop but all of a sudden on the window appeared a script 'This folder is empty'.
Today I reset my phone but no any difference.
My question is why my Nexus 6 couldn't be open as a folder on my laptop?
Now I can't remove files from the phone or to place file in it.
Any clues?

Comment: Is it connected as an MTP Device? When you plug it in you should get a notification, clicking on the notification will tell/allow you to choose the mode it is connected in. (sorry, I can't tell you the notification name in detail - I don't have a USB cable handy)

Answer (score -1):

When you connect the phone using USB, a notification comes up saying USB for charging. You just need to click on it to change the setting. [Ankush's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133937/why-my-nexus-6-dosnt-open-as-a-folder-on-my-laptop/134488#comment168514_133937) helped me arrive at the solution.